# Remove div and append new div at the same position

Tags: jquery, html

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="like-post old" data-postid="242">Like Post</div>
```

I want a jquery code to remove the div that has class like-post and append the new content to the position of the removed div.

Let's say that the new content is:

```
<div class="like-post new" data-postid"232">Like Post</div>
```

The problem that if i use something like `.html()` method the final code will be:

```
<div class="like-post" data-postid"232">
    <div class="like-post new" data-postid"232">Like Post</div>
</div>
```

The final code that i need is:

```
<div class="like-post new" data-postid"232">
   Like Post
</div>
```

Comment: What should be the output? What have you tried?

Comment: you can make a div with an id  or class whatever, and you can change its content/html with what you want. because when you remove old div you dont know where to put new

Comment: @void i edit the question please take a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [**`.replaceWith()`**](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) function.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".like-post").replaceWith('<div class="newClass">Hello!</div>');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-post old" data-postid="242">I'll be replaced... :(</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the whole div and the putting a new div at the same place (though, which can be done using [`.replaceWith`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)), the better approach I would suggest here to change the value of the attributes like `class, data-postid` and change the `HTML` if required.

See the code below:

```js
$(".like-post")
  .toggleClass("old new")
  .attr("data-postid", "232")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="like-post old" data-postid="242">Like Post</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to simply alter the `old` div to reflect what the new div needs to have?  For example:

```
$('.like-post:not(.new)').addClass('new');
```

This will select all `div`s with the class `like-post` that do not have the class `new`, and will add the class `new`.

Then you don't have to worry about removing anything, or adding anything in the exact correct spot.